# Select from Listbox populated by selecting from another Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have two Listboxes. Clicking on an item of the first Listbox inserts information in the second one.

When I click on one of the inserted items, I get an error.

The listboxes are defined as:

```
list_1 = Listbox(root,selectmode=SINGLE)
list_2 = Listbox(root,selectmode=SINGLE)
```

To get the selected item:

```
list_1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelect)
```

which refers to:

```
def CurSelect(evt):
        list_2.delete(0,END)
        selected = list_1.get(list_1.curselection())

        for i in range(2):
            list_2.insert(END,i)
```

Clicking on one item of list_1 inserts items in list_2.

If I select an item of List_2 this appears:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call
__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "unbenannt.py", line 28, in CurSelect
    selected = liste.get(liste.curselection())
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2792, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a
 number
```

I had this kind of problem when selecting in the first Listbox, but solved it with << ListboxSelect>>.

Previously clicking items in the second Listbox worked, although I didn't change anything since then.

Full Code Example:

```
from tkinter import *

class Code():
    def __init__(self):
        Code.Window(self)

    def Window(self):
        root = Tk()

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.grid(row=4,rowspan=3,column=1,sticky=N+S+W)

        liste = Listbox(root,selectmode=SINGLE,width=12,yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        liste.grid(row=4,rowspan=3,column=0)

        for j in range(2):
            liste.insert(END,j+5)

        scrollbar.config(command=liste.yview)
        scrollbar_2 = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar_2.grid(row=4,rowspan=3,column=3,sticky=N+S+W)

        eintrag = Listbox(root,selectmode=SINGLE,yscrollcommand=scrollbar_2.set)
        eintrag.grid(row=4,rowspan=3,column=2,sticky=W)

        def CurSelect(evt):
            eintrag.delete(0,END)
            selected = liste.get(liste.curselection())
            for i in range(2):
                eintrag.insert(END,str(i)+str(selected))

        liste.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelect)

        root.mainloop()

Code()
```

This example doesn't make anything useful, but the problem appears anyway.

Comment: Pleaser create a complete [mcve].

Comment: ok just a moment

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. However, it's clear that this code does not produce the error you say it does. Please post _actual_ code and the _actual_ error that you get.

Comment: Its clear for me, that when I run this exact Code it produce this error. I try update my Anaconda Library, but I don't understand why this happens though

Comment: Your "full code example" doesn't have anything named `list_1`, which is what is in the error message.

Comment: Okay, but with a little bit thinkin you would see, that the Name itself is not the problem und you could just overthink the names, but i changed it though, Maybe You could now help with the problem, not with the typography

Comment: It's your responsibility to accurately post code and the error generated by the code. I have no way of knowing if the code is correct and the error is wrong, or the error is correct and the code is wrong. I'm not complaining about the typography; this is a technical forum, accuracy matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default only one listbox can have a selection at a time. When you select something in the second listbox, the selection is removed from the first listbox. When that happens, your binding fires but your bound function assumes that `liste.curselection()` returns a non-empty string.

The simplest solution is to allow both listboxes to have a selection at the same time. You do that by setting the `exportselection` attribute to `False`:

```
liste = Listbox(..., exportselection=False)
...
eintrag = Listbox(..., exportselection=False)
```

Comment: Thank You a lot, that worked just fine for me and ist exactly what I wanted, sorry if my responds semmed agressive in any Way.

I understaand the problem, but wouldn't have thought about it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The error raises because when the right-hand-side list box, `eintrag`, gets focus, any item selected in the left-hand-side list box,`liste`, gets *deselected* and that invokes the event callback for `'<<ListboxSelect>>'` in which it is assumed that `liste.curselection()` is *never* empty, which is untrue in this particular case and thus `liste.get(liste.curselection())` throws the error as it tries to get an item that is in the index of `""`.

Nesting entire event handler with an `if` resolves the issue:

```
def CurSelect(evt):
    if liste.curselection(): # To call below statements only when liste has a selected item
        eintrag.delete(0,END)
        selected = liste.get(liste.curselection())
        for i in range(2):
            eintrag.insert(END,str(i)+str(selected))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is aswell a functional answer!